# Regular expression test

Tags: javascript, regex

This regular expression in javascript

```
var foo = RegExp("^https?:\/\/(\w+\.)*youtube\.([a-zA-Z0-9])+");
```

will match strings like: [The below statements returns true]

```
foo.test("http://www.youtube.com");
foo.test("https://www.youtube.com");
foo.test("http://youtube.com");
```

But the same test fails if the expression is:

```
var foo_fail = RegExp("^https?:\/\/(\w+\.)*youtube\.\w+");
```

This RegExp should have passed the above tests but I see:
foo_fail.test("http://www.youtube.com"); returns false on chrome/firebug console. This should have returned true. What's wrong in this expression?

The similar expression if run on perl returns successful match which is expected.

Comment: Don't you want to use `"^https?:\/\/(\w+\.)*youtube\.(\w)+"` with a backslash before the last "w"? Another difference is the missing capture group around the `\w`. `\w` should also allow underscores and possibly non-latin characters, so your regexes are not equivalent any way.

Comment: @amon: Missing capture group? It's for use with `test`, so that makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks. I still get the test failure. I modified the question.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a backslash before the `w`:

```
\.\w+
```

Further, for static regular expressions, *never* use the `[new] RegExp()` syntax, but rather regular expression literals:

```js
var foo = /^https?:\/\/(\w+\.)*youtube\.\w+/;
```

Comment: @user1558887: Take my second piece of advice, please. The current problem is that, since you are within a string, the escaped characters are simply stripped of their backslashes. Use a regular expression literal.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. var foo_fail = RegExp("^https?:\/\/(\w+\.)*youtube\.\\w+");

Comment: @user1558887: Not for the reason you think. Please take my advice and use a regular expression literal.

Comment: Thanks minitech. The regular expression literal works. I need to understand the reason why we need to have double escape at the end of expression in RegExp `\\w+` whereas earlier in the expression it was not needed

Comment: @user1558887: It *was* actually needed, you just didn't notice. The `\w+` silently became `w+` - but that was no problem, because you only tested it against `www`, which does match `w+` :) The `.`s match any character, so they wouldn't have caused problems either, and you only need to escape forward slashes in regular expression literals, so those were fine too.